# When using compiled templates in angular, css properties not available in component $onInit

Tags: angularjs

First some context. I have a component that relies on absolute positioning of elements based on text width. To accomplish this, I wrote a service to calculate text width given a string and the element which will contain it. I use jQuery's .css() function to build a font string which I can then use with the canvas API to get text width.

```
function getTextWidth(text, referenceElement) {

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var fontCss = '';
    fontCss += ' ' + referenceElement.css('font-style');
    fontCss += ' ' + referenceElement.css('font-variant');
    fontCss += ' ' + referenceElement.css('font-weight');
    fontCss += ' ' + referenceElement.css('font-size');
    fontCss += '/' + referenceElement.css('line-height');
    fontCss += ' ' + referenceElement.css('font-family');

    context.font = fontCss;
    return context.measureText(text).width;

}
```

The problem. While this was working great in dev, it failed in QA. The .css() method was returning undefined for everything. My investigation led to the fact that we compile templates to javascript in our build process. Evidently, when an Angular component is using a $http-loaded template the page styles get applied to it immediately and are available when $onInit runs. But when the template is pre-loaded, the styles are not yet applied when $onInit runs.

The question. Is there any way short of applying a $timeout hack to ensure styles are applied to the template before code is run?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, just adding `$timeout(getTextWidth(yourText, yourElement))` instead of `getTextWidth(yourText, yourElement)` (assuming that's how you wrote it) in the $onInit should be enough to make sure the element is rendered properly before questionning its css.